# unable to find multiple existing element with selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

here is the html code of the Links i am trying to click on (i dont know why selenium cant locate the link. My guess is, that there are X amounts of the link. The only difference is the string in the brackets of onclick.) Underneath i'll show you 2 examples of the html code. I'd like to click on all of them (in this case on both)!

1. Button or Link:

   ```html
   <td class="text-right">
     <a href="#"onclick="doRetrievePnr('DUA75J')"  id="viewPnr">Ansehen</a></td>
   ```
2. Button or Link:

```html
<td class="text-right">
  <a href="#" onclick="doRetrievePnr('C574DC')" id="viewPnr">Ansehen</a></td>
```

here are my Attempts to click on the button:

1. `driver.find_element_by_link_text("doRetrievePnr('DUA75J')").click()`
2. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@onclick='doRetrievePnr('DUA75J')']").click()`

Here are the Errors i get:

1. `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"doRetrievePnr('DUA75J')"}`
2. `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@onclick='doRetrievePnr('DUA75J')'] because of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[@onclick='doRetrievePnr('DUA75J')']' is not a valid XPath expression.`

am I missing out on something?

***EDIT***
[Heres a picture of the BUTTONS, the HTML CODE and my PYTHON CODE (lines 34 & 35)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEAlH.jpg)

Comment: `By_Link_text` is the link TEXT, that's the bit between the tag, i.e. `Ansehen`  ... Your xpath you're suffering from quote-issue. It looks like too many single quotes and i expect it's terminating part way through..  Happy to have a look at the page and feedback an answer, can you share a link to it?

Comment: @RichEdwards I have to log in to that website in order to see it. But i'll try to screenshot the page with the html code! Just give me a second.

Comment: If you want to click on all of them, you can do `find_elements`  (note it's plural) - and use id  `viewPnr`  - then iterate through the results to interact with each one

Comment: @RichEdwards i added a more Detailed picture! In the meantime i'll try the plural method. I tried it before but maybe i can do it this time.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments - getting all the items of a specific identifier can be done with `find_elements_by_...` (note find element**s** - it's plural)

That returns an array you can iterate through to interact with each element.

It looks like all your links have the same ID.

Something like this might work:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_id('viewPnr')
for link in links:
    link.click()
    time.sleep(10) #replace this with what you want to do
```

Obviously if you're clicking links and the page changes this might not work after the first iteration. However, this is the concept on how you can get all objects and iterate through them.

Comment: I think i figured it out! I'll try it out and i'll let you know if it worked or not. Give me a little time :D